# Find covariance of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A bag contains $20$ red balls, $60$ green balls and $20$ blue balls. $5$ balls are drawn from the bag with replacement in such a way that any ball is equally likely to be drawn. Let, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ denotes the number of red, green, blue ball drawn respectively. Using $Var(X)$, $Var(Z)$ and $Var(X+Z)$ find out $Cov(X,Z)$.

There are total $100$ balls. Probability of drawing red ball is $20/100=1/5$.

Now, $P(X=1)= {5\choose 1} \frac 15 (\frac 45)^4$, $P(X=2)= {5\choose 2} (\frac 15)^2 (\frac 45)^3$, ..., $P(X=5)= {5\choose 5} (\frac 15)^5 (\frac 45)^0$.

Then, $E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^5 xP(X=x)=1.2048$.

Is it correct ? If so, then in similar way we can find out $Var(X)$ and $Var(Z)$.

But how to find out $Var(X+Z)$ ?

Comment: It should be clear, that X,Y and Z have binomial distribution. So has X+Z. Just imagine you could not see a difference between blue and red. That gives you the parameter for the binomial distribution of X+Z.

Comment: @PeterStrouvelle Right. So here $X$ and $Z$ both are $B(5,\frac 15)$ and then $X+Z$ is $B(10,\frac 15)$ Is it correct ?

Comment: The number of draws does not change. But now there are 40 balls either red oder blue. So the probability to have k non-green balls in 5 draws is $\binom{5}{k}(\frac{20+20}{100})^k(\frac{60}{100})^{5-k}$. So X+Z is B(5,2/5).